# Автоматически прописывать в форме отправки строку заголовка при клике "узнать цену"

Tags: email, html, php

Всем доброго дня, вопрос назрел.

Пример, есть блок с товаром, например.  и всплывающая форма заявки.

Примерный код

```
<div> 
**заголовок**
картинка

<a>узнать цену </a>
</div>
```

Форма

```
<form>
**заголовок**
имя
телефон
 </form>
```

При клике "узнать цену" - строка заголовка автоматически прописывалась в форме отправки.
есть ли какой вариант это сделать.

Comment: > При клике "узнать цену" - строка заголовка автоматически прописывалась в форме отправки.

а теперь не прописывается ?

Comment: не не, и раньше не прописывалась.

просто интересно, как реализовать так, чтобы из блока, куда нажимают узнать цену, выдирался заголовок в форму связи.

Comment: Ну... нужен javascript =)
Из тегов я так и не понял, на чем у вас там все это работает. Используются ли js фреймворки?

Comment: так без разницы, можно подключить же. :)

пример.
http://spectexkomplekt.ru/dvuhetazhnyy-avtovoz-evakuator-gaz-33106-valday

нажимаем узнать цену - и видим в форме заголовок страницы.

но это заголовок, тут все понятно.

а если на страницы две кнопки - узнать цену модели, и в форме указывался тот заголовок, к чьей форме относиться кнопка "узнать цену"

Comment: Вот так наподключаете к сайту скриптов на мегабайты, и будете пользоваться ими от силы на 2%. Нет, такие вещи определяются заранее и меняются не просто так.

Comment: так в том то и дело, что все чисто, скриптов нет. этот первый)

Answer (score 1):

Ну при рендере страницы на севрере указывайте id заголовка и кнопки, потом узнавайте id и заполняйте. Вот пример с jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/mk0vy16p/1/

HTML:

```
<div class='header' data-product-id='1'>Товар 1</div>
<button class='get_price' data-product-id='1'>Узнать цену</button>

<div class='header' data-product-id='2'>Товар 2</div>
<button class='get_price' data-product-id='2'>Узнать цену</button>

<div class='header' data-product-id='3'>Товар 3</div>
<button class='get_price' data-product-id='3'>Узнать цену</button>

<div class='header' data-product-id='4'>Товар 4</div>
<button class='get_price' data-product-id='4'>Узнать цену</button>

...

<input id='product_header'>
```

JS:

```
$('.get_price').on('click', function () {
    var product_id = $(this).data('product-id');
    var header = $('[class=header][data-product-id='+product_id+']');
    $('#product_header').val(header.html());
});
```

Про data-* есть тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/139210/

Comment: о , спс :) ценный ответ